PHP and Postgresql : consecutive insert
I have two tables related by foreign key.
To register a user, I want to consecutively insert his informations in info table and credentials in access table.
But when the second insert fails (for any reason), I would like to cancel (delete) the first one.
Here is part of the code :
    // Data going to table "info"
    $info = array(
        "fname" => $_POST["fname"],
        "lname"=> $_POST["lname"]
    );

    // if insert into table "info" is successfull
    if ($lastInsertID = $this->model->addUser("info", $info)) {
        
    // Data going to table "access"
        $access = array(
            "id" => $lastInsertID,
            "password" => $_POST["password"],
            "group" => "users",
            "privilege" => 0,
        );

        // insert into table "access"
        if ($this->model->addUser("access", $access)) {
                echo json_encode(array("success"));
        }
        
        else {
            // if insert into table "access" fails
            // remove the last insert  into table "info"
            $this->model->deleteUser("info", $lastInsertID);
            echo json_encode(array("error", "access"));
        }
    }
    else echo json_encode(array("error", "info"));




The problem is that if the second insert (in table "access") fails, the code to remove the last insert into table "info" is not executed. I only get in return the SQLSTATE exception
and the single row in table "info" remains
How can I improve my code ? Or Is there a better way to handle "consecutive insert" with php and postgresql ?

Read about transactions.

Thanks Alex. I admit to be a newbie on postgresql (I only know the CRUD actions but not too much). But I'm a go deeper into that to see.

It's not specifically for PostgreSQL, almost any database supports transactions.

Got it @FrankHeikens ! I've found what I needeed at https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-php/transaction/.

Can you also show us your addUser() method?

Use Transaction:
You can Start a TRANSACTOIN. Then do addUser().
if your actions succeed COMMIT it, otherwise ROLLBACK it.
Add some simple wrapper methods in your model class:
// I don't know your names (class name, variable names, ...), So I use sample names

class DataModel {
  /* your current code */

  public function beginTransaction()
  { $this->db_connection->beginTransaction(); }

  public function commit()
  { $this->db_connection->commit(); }

  public function rollBack()
  { $this->db_connection->rollBack(); }
}

Now call transaction methods in your code:
    // Begin a transaction
    $this->model->beginTransaction(); // <=====

    // Data going to table "info"
    $info = array(
        "fname" => $_POST["fname"],
        "lname"=> $_POST["lname"]
    );

    // if insert into table "info" is successfull
    if ($lastInsertID = $this->model->addUser("info", $info)) {
        
        // Data going to table "access"
        $access = array(
            "id" => $lastInsertID,
            "password" => $_POST["password"],
            "group" => "users",
            "privilege" => 0,
        );

        // insert into table "access"
        if ($this->model->addUser("access", $access)) {
            // Commit changes; Write changes to database actually.
            $this->model->commit(); // <=====

            echo json_encode(array("success"));
        }

        else {
            // if insert into table "access" fails
            // RollBack; Cancel all changes you make in your transaction.
            $this->model->rollBack(); // <=====enter code here
            echo json_encode(array("error", "access"));
        }
    }
    else echo json_encode(array("error", "info"));


That's nearly what I ended up doing. I wrapped the transaction into a try-catch instead of an if-else as you did. But it worked. Very usefull @safineh. Thanks !

If the above answer resolved your issue, or lead you to the solution, then kindly accept it. This aids future users having the same or similar issue and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.

Hi @Belayer. Didn't know about that rule of the community (cause newbie). But I assure you I don't have any laziness of being gratefull or helpfull. Thanks for your suggestion.

Understand,  it too is a learning process.
